# wx._core.PyDeadObjectError when switching frames in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, combobox, wxpython

I have I problem when switching between pages in my wx.ComboBox.  The error seems to be when to change pages more then twice. This is a huge bug for me that I can't seem to find a solution for.  Code:

```
import wx
ok=[]
class oranges(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing Sample',size=(1024,768))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
        some_text=wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'TEXT',pos=(500,500))
        more_choices=['Home','Page One']
        self.adding=wx.ComboBox(self.frame,choices=more_choices,pos=(300,722),style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX,self.addition,self.adding)
    def addition(self,event):
        if self.adding.GetValue()=='Home':
            for i in ok:
                i.Destroy()
            ok.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'Oranges',pos=(300,300)))
        elif self.adding.GetValue()=='Page One':
            for i in ok:
                i.Destroy()
            ok.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'Apples',pos=(300,300)))
        else: pass
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance and I can't wait to see the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get your error is because you kill the objects in `ok` but *don't actually remove them from the list.*  That's bad since you then have dead husks of widgets floating around in your program.  Here's how your iteration of the list looks as you go through each line of `addition`:

**First Time:**

```
for i in ok:                                                      #[]
    i.Destroy()                                                   #[]
ok.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'Oranges',pos=(300,300)))   #[<wx object with oranges>]
```

**Second Time:**

```
for i in ok:                                                      #[<wx object with oranges>]
    i.Destroy()                                                   #[<wx object with oranges>]]
ok.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'Oranges',pos=(300,300)))   #[<dead husk>, <wx object with apples>]
```

**Third Time:**

```
for i in ok:                                                      #[<dead husk>, <wx object with apples>]
    i.Destroy()                                                   #[<dead husk>, <wx object with apples>]
```

When Python loops over `Ok` and tries to apply `Destroy` to the dead husk, it breaks since the object has been killed.  **Killing this object does not remove it from the list**.

I got your code to work by resetting `ok` before the new object is appended.  **However**, I had to make `ok` a class attribute.  Working code below with diagnostic print statements:

```
import wx
class oranges(wx.Frame):
    ok=[]

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing Sample',size=(1024,768))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
        some_text=wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'TEXT',pos=(500,500))
        more_choices=['Home','Page One']
        self.adding=wx.ComboBox(self.frame,choices=more_choices,pos=(300,722),style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX,self.addition,self.adding)
    def addition(self,event):
        if self.adding.GetValue()=='Home':
            print "1 ", self.ok
            for i in self.ok:
                i.Destroy()
            self.ok = []
            self.ok.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'Oranges',pos=(300,300)))
            print "2 ", self.ok
        elif self.adding.GetValue()=='Page One':
            print "3 ", self.ok
            for i in self.ok:
                i.Destroy()
            self.ok = []
            self.ok.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'Apples',pos=(300,300)))
            print "4 ", self.ok
        else: pass
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That was super informative and I am super glad you took the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

As @wnnmaw already explained masterfully, the reason for your troble is that you destroy your objects only partially.

I simplified your code:

```
for i in ok:
    i.Destroy()
```

to (EDIT, most easiest way **ever**)

```
for _ in ok:
    el = ok.pop()
    el.Destroy()
```

destroying the element and popping (removing) it from the list in one operation group.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is happening with the `range(0,len(ok))`. Could you please explain this more? Thanks for answering!

Comment: The expression just goes over all elements in the list without actually assigning the result of the looping to anything. You are right, this is more complicated than necessary. See edit for the easiest way.

Comment: @user3818089, its actually better to do it the original way. Removing elements from a list while iterating through it is poor practice and error likely.

Comment: @wnnmaw: [citation needed] *SCNR*